# How to sort videos into folders?

Tags: itunes, iphone

How can I sort videos into folders/categories using iTunes ?

I've tried adding info to the sorting field tab when I click on 'Get Info' after right clicking on the video itself. But the videos always appear in a list on my iPhone. I just want to nest some videos into folders. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your movies into Genres, that is the only way I have found to sort of make a subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't.

I've never put a TV series on my iPhone or iPad, so I am not sure if the series are grouped together per season (as they are on an AppleTV), but movies will always appear on a single level.